# SQL Impala convert NaN values to NULL values

Tags: sql, null, nan, implicit-conversion, impala

I have the following column in my table:

| col 1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| NULL |
| NaN |
| 5 |

"Bad" aggregations return NaN instead of NULL and the variable is type DOUBLE in the end.
I want to have one type of missing values only, hence I need to convert NULL to NaN or the other way around.
My problem is that when I partition with a window function it does not recognize NaNs as equal to
NULLS and creates separate subgroups, which is something I do not want.
Any suggestions on how to convert them?

Comment: can you not replace this `NaN` with null like `if(col1='NaN',null,col1)` ?